# Getting "the requested resource is in use" when using asio::async_write in single thread

Tags: c++, boost, tcp, boost-asio, asio

Here is my code.

```
boost::asio::async_write(*serialPort, boost::asio::buffer(*something),handler);
boost::asio::async_write(*serialPort, boost::asio::buffer(*something2),handler);
```

The above code will get an error "the requested resource is in use"  on the second line (Note that the async stream is a serial port). But when I changed the stream to a tcp socket, everthing works fine. Why?

Now I know I can’t use these composed asynchronous operation these way, but the first line code may be a heartbeat package, the second line may be a package which don’t sent regually. And these send operations buffers can’t gather together in the same time. Is there a way to synchronize these asynchronous operations in a single thread ( or multi-thread)?

Comment: That only works by accident, a tcp write is more likely to complete synchronously because the OS uses a larger buffer for the socket.  Consider getting ahead by simply merging the two buffers so a single write gets the job done.

Comment: Please research how to do async I/O with ASIO. You need to fire one async operation, providing a completion callback, in which you can fire the next one.

Answer (score 0):

The commenters are right. In this case you can easily use a buffer sequence (["scatter/gather IO"](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/buffer.html#boost_asio.reference.buffer.buffers_and_scatter_gather_i_o)):

```
std::vector<boost::asio::const_buffer> buffers { 
    boost::asio::buffer(*something), 
    boost::asio::buffer(*something2) 
};

boost::asio::async_write(*serialPort, buffers, handler);
```

See it **<kbd>[Compiling On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/346c21fb7263004d)</kbd>**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/serial_port.hpp>

void handler(boost::system::error_code ec, size_t) {
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << ": " << ec.message() << "\n";
}

int main() {
    boost::asio::io_service svc;

    auto serialPort = std::make_shared<boost::asio::serial_port>(svc);

    auto something = std::make_shared<std::string>("hello world\n");
    auto something2 = std::make_shared<std::string>("bye world\n");

    std::vector<boost::asio::const_buffer> buffers { 
        boost::asio::buffer(*something), 
        boost::asio::buffer(*something2) 
    };

    boost::asio::async_write(*serialPort, buffers, handler);
}
```